# How do I add custom dropdowns using a custom module in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I am having trouble with a custom module where I would like to add a custom dropdown.  What I would like is to have a couple of items preset for the dropdown but have it show up in the dropdown editor so the admin can change or add more items to the dropdown.  I have played around with it for quite a while and can't get it to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Dependent Dropdowns in Sugar 6.5 are what you are looking for...

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/05/03/new-for-sugar-6-5-create-dependent-dropdowns-using-sugar-logic-in-studio/

Answer (score 0):

SugarCRM doesn't seem to allow you to use the data of a module in (multi-)select of another module. Despite having a relationship set between the modules as such.